# Windows 7 Bluecreen Diagnosis

Tags: windows-7, diagnostic

I have been getting these bluescreens once or twice every month and I have no idea whats causing it.

Is there anyone who can show me how to diagnose it?

[image: Bluescreen pic]

Comment: Do you have an ATI graphics card? Are they running latest drivers? Is the card over-heating?

Comment: Use software to monitor temperatures, and run Prime95 in blend mode, if the pc locks up instantly it's probably a faulty memory or PSU, if it locks in about 30 mins, check temperatures thoroughly. Please report the results.

Comment: I run 280x Turbo Duo in crossfire and i have the latest drivers. I used prime95 with not much happening. Temps peaked at 69c with 4770k. I will make an update later when i have done some gpu benchmark to test the temps.